# Is there a rule prescribing the absence of the -eth third person ending in late middle English?

Tags: grammar, middle-english

Is there a rule prescribing the absence of the *-eth* third person ending in late middle English ?

In the King James Bible, there are many verses which contain verbs in the third person without the -eth a the end, for example :

> Psalm 7:2 Lest **he tear** my soul like a lion, rending it in pieces, while there is none to deliver.

Is there a particular reason for this ? Would "Lest he teareth" have been correct ?

(I've been thinking that maybe it was a subjunctive, that wouldn't take the ending or something of the sort)

Comment: The King James Version is actually Early Modern English rather than Late Middle English. (I mean, there's no single universally-accepted date for the line between LME and EModE, but I think the KJV is quite comfortably inside the latter.)

Answer (score 7):

You’re right. In that sentence the plain form of the verb, *tear*, performs a subjunctive role to express a hypothetical meaning.

Comment: +1. Even in Present-Day English, *lest* takes the subjunctive, at least in the U.S.; for example, so far this month, *The New York Times* has had "lest the happy couple think [...]", "lest any detail leak out and inflame [...]", "lest the wealth of [...] be seen to [...]", and "lest anyone think [...]".

Comment: It does, but, as you hint, the subjunctive seems to remain more prevalent in American English than in British English, where _lest_ itself is confined mainly to formal contexts.